# Mocking axios with Jest throws error “Cannot read property 'interceptors' of undefined”

Tags: javascript, jestjs, axios

I’m having trouble mocking axios with Jest and react-testing-library. I’m stuck on an error around axios interceptors and can’t make my way around it.

This is my `api.js` file:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: window.apiPath,
  withCredentials: true,
});

api.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  const newConfig = Object.assign({}, config);
  newConfig.headers.Accept = 'application/json';

  return newConfig;
}, error => Promise.reject(error));
```

The call to api in my component:

```js
const fetchAsync = async endpoint => {
  const result = await api.get(endpoint);
  setSuffixOptions(result.data.data);
};
```

Then in my spec file:

```js
jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    create: jest.fn(),
    get: jest.fn(),
    interceptors: {
      request: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
      response: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
    },
  };
});

test('fetches and displays data', async () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<Condition {...props} />);
  await expect(getByText(/Current milestone/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

The test fails with this message:

```sh
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'interceptors' of undefined

       6 | });
       7 |
    >  8 | api.interceptors.request.use(config => {
         |                ^
       9 |   const newConfig = Object.assign({}, config);
      10 |   newConfig.headers.Accept = 'application/json';
      11 |
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

the `create` method is what creates the api which has the `get` and `interceptors` methods. So you need to create a dummy api object:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => {
  return {
    create: jest.fn(() => ({
      get: jest.fn(),
      interceptors: {
        request: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() },
        response: { use: jest.fn(), eject: jest.fn() }
      }
    }))
  }
})
```

Comment: are you sure this will work? I tried it but no luck. I had to do axios module mock to make it work. @cyberwombat

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth definitely worked though that was a bit back. Perhaps the internals of axios have changed?

Comment: axios might have changed it's internals but this seems a very clean mocking but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth I looked at axios core and it seems to still use `create`. If you want to make a sandbox I can take a peek.

Answer (score 3):

You must mock api.js, not Axios.

```
    import { FuncToCallAPI } from './funcAPI';
    import api from './api';

    describe('Mock api.ts', () => {
      it('should get data', async () => {
       
        const Expected = { status: 200, data: {} };

        jest.spyOn(api, 'get').mockResolvedValue(Expected);

        const result = await FuncToCallAPI('something');

        expect(result).toEqual(Expected);
  });
});
```

Then create a test for api.js, mocking the axios.create as you did before.